# Large arrays using preprocessor directives in C

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

Is the following a valid syntax? If yes, the please explain how it works .

```
double array[SIZE][SIZE] = {
    #include "float_values.txt"
}
```

Comment: did you try it? The C pre processor....

Comment: No; there's a semicolon missing after the close brace — unless the included file contains something like: `{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }; int abs(int i) { return (i < 0) ? -i : i;`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is valid C syntax.

In C and C++, `#include` directives are very simple: they just copy and paste the contents of the file you're using into the current file, replacing the `#include` directive.

For example, if your "float_values.txt" file looked like this:

```
{1.0, 2.0},
{3.0, 4.0}
```

Then the preprocessor would transform your code to look like this:

```
double array[SIZE][SIZE] = {
    {1.0, 2.0},
    {3.0, 4.0} 
}
```

However, you must ensure `SIZE` is defined correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code snippet is valid.

The preprocessor will find the `#include` directive and search for a file named `float_values.txt` within the given search paths. Then the contents of that file will be taken and `#include "float_values.txt"` will be replaced with the contents of the file.
If the resulting code is valid purely depends on the content of the file.
To be valid, the file must contain data to initialize a two dimensional array of doubles, but must not contain more values than permitted by the value of `SIZE`.
Less values would be okay as the remaining doubles would be default initialized.